# How do I prevent applications from restoring after a factory reset?

Tags: applications, factory-reset

I have a lot of apps I don't really use, and my phone has been misbehaving as of late.  I'm thinking about just doing a factory reset, but the last time I did one, it restored all my applications, I believe based on my Google/Android Market account.

Is there a way to prevent this so I have to 'opt-in' to all my stupid apps?  Or at the very least be able to remove the apps from the web interface versus going to the app on the phone...hitting uninstall...waiting...repeat a few dozen times?

Comment: I think you get the option to enable or disable Google's auto-backup/restore when you configure the first account on the phone, but I guess that would also apply to other settings (I think it stores wifi network settings and things of that nature, too). Also don't know any way to turn it off after the initial config.

Answer (score 4):

Before doing the factory reset, you can turn off backup by unchecking `Settings -> Privacy -> Back up my data`.  The Market will remember your paid apps.  If you're not going to root and use something like Titanium Backup for the other apps you do want to keep, you could do something like `ls /data/app > /sdcard/apps.txt` to record what apps you have and then refer to it afterwards, or use something like [App List Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.punsoftware.backup).

Comment: Thanks for recommending App List Backup. That's pretty nifty.